# Two column in one datafield - Devexpress Angular

Tags: angular, devextreme-angular

How to combine two columns in just one dataField?

```
 <dxi-column
    dataField="[Year, Make, Model]"
    caption="Vehicle"
    width="auto"
    [minWidth]="100"
  ></dxi-column>
```

I want to combine the Year, Make, and Model field in just one column, resulting their values will just separated by a space when displayed on a table.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it using [cellTemplate]

```
<dxi-column
    cellTemplate="vehicleTemplate"
    caption="Vehicle"
    width="auto"
    [minWidth]="100"
></dxi-column>

<div *dxTemplate="let item of 'vehicleTemplate'">
    <p class="">{{ item.data.Year }} {{ item.data.Make }} {{ item.data.Model }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But if anyone data is coming as null like :

{{ item.data.Year }} ({{ item.data.Make }}) and Make is null/no data in few rows then instead of showing the empty (), it should only show the Year. How to do it?